# Can I change the mouse button bindings in Netbeans?

Tags: mouse, netbeans, keymap, key-binding

Is it possible to change the bindings for `mouse4` and `mouse5` (the thumb buttons) in Netbeans? I can't find any option in the NB keymapper, nor can I find anything on Google!

I'm using Netbeans v7.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. But you can vote for this [bug/issue](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=70961). You'll have to create an account for the bugzilla site if don't allready have one.

Answer (score 3):

What I've done to accomplish the desired result is bound my mouse buttons to keystroke combinations and then map those combinations in Netbeans.

Depending on your mouse manufacturer but it really helps if it already comes with a software to allow overall and per-program custom button bindings (e.g. in my case [SetPoint by Logitech](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/articles/win8-setpoint) made it an ease - with a caveat of the middle button for which it is unable to support per-program binding for my M510).

If such manufacturer provided software isn't an option for your mouse you could accomplish the same result with AutoHotkey and the [Remapping Keys and Buttons](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) docs. e.g.

```
XButton1::Shift - Makes the fourth mouse button behave like the Shift key.
```

The Remarks section also covers how to make a binding for a specific window so you could have more freedom in what and how you decide to map.

Comment: Non-programmable mouse-users will shake their heads in agony about this but yeah, totally works, thanks! How does Netbeans not have this feature yet?

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on @Jaaks answer, here is an example autohotkey script, which remaps mouse4 to Alt+<- and mouse5 to Alt+-> in order to navigate forwards/backwards in netbeans:

```
if WinActive("NetBeans IDE ahk_class SunAwtFrame") 
XButton1::
  Send {Alt Down}
  Send {Left}
  Sleep 10
  Send {Alt Up}
return

XButton2::
  Send {Alt Down}
  Send {Right}
  Sleep 10
  Send {Alt Up}
return
```